# How do I parse a complicated string to an array using one of those preg_ functions?

Tags: php, parsing

I have something like this:

```
[
    "username=required:true|min:2|max:14",
    "email=required:true|email:true",
    "password=required:true|min:6|max:22",
    "passwordRepeat=required:true|match:password"
]
```

and I want to

```
[
    "username" => [
        "required"  => true,
        "min"       => 2,
        "max"       => 14,
    ],
    "email" => [
        "required"  => true,
        "email"     => true,
    ],
    "password" => [
        "required"  => true,
        "min"       => 6,
        "max"       => 22,
    ],
    "passwordRepeat" => [
        "required"  => true,
        "match"     => "password"
    ]
]
```

and I tried a lot using those preg_* functions, but I still didn't managed to get the right pattern. Can someone help me with this? I appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: Why don't you show us what you tried?

Answer (score 2):

Why use regular expressions when you can [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) repeatedly?

Everyone likes explosions. Let's do that.

---

#### Explodes!:

```
$parts = [
    "username=required:true|min:2|max:14",
    "email=required:true|email:true",
    "password=required:true|min:6|max:22",
    "passwordRepeat=required:true|match:password"
];

$result = [];
foreach ($parts as $part) {
    list($property, $attributes) = explode('=', $part, 2);
    foreach (explode("|", $attributes) as $attribute) {
        list($name, $value) = explode(":", $attribute, 2);
        $result[$property][$name] = $value;
    }
}

var_export($result);
```

---

#### Boom!:

```
array (
  'username' => 
  array (
    'required' => 'true',
    'min' => '2',
    'max' => '14',
  ),
  'email' => 
  array (
    'required' => 'true',
    'email' => 'true',
  ),
  'password' => 
  array (
    'required' => 'true',
    'min' => '6',
    'max' => '22',
  ),
  'passwordRepeat' => 
  array (
    'required' => 'true',
    'match' => 'password',
  ),
)
```